# Making a panel show up when a rig or duplicate of rig is selected

Tags: scripting, rigging

I want to script a rig and I want to make a panel for it. Is there a way for this panel to only show up when this rig or duplicates of this rig are selected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can implement similar solution as Rigify uses. You can use a custom property to differentiate your rig from other. The panel will show only when a selected armature has that property set to specific value. You can test it in the panel's @classmethod.

Comment: What is this property? How can it be used? Also, does the person using this rig have to have rigify enabled?

Comment: Here is what you need to know: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html